# C# cast to another class with recursion

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, recursion

I am developing a MVC Project with Entity framework and i have a category table like this :

```
public partial class Categories
{
    public Categories()
    {
        this.Categories1 = new HashSet<Categories>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RelatedCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Categories> Categories1 { get; set; } //Children
    public virtual Categories Categories2 { get; set; } //Parent
}
```

When i get table data with EF, it gives me the object i want. Parents with children.

```
    class Program
    {
        static Entities db = new Entities();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Categories> categories = db.Categories.Where(item => item.RelatedId == null).ToList();
        }
}
```

With `relatedId == null` part, i get the main categories which has no parent.

There is no problem this far. But i want to cast `categories` object which ef returned to another class which is :

```
public class NewCategories
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private List<NewCategories> _subCategories;

    public NewCategories()
    {
        _subCategories= new List<NewCategories>();
    }

    public List<NewCategories> SubCategories { get { return _subCategories; } }
}
```

And i want new `List<NewCategories> newCategories` object.

How can i accomplish that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to put in the `SubCategories`?

Comment: Same logic with `List<Categories> categories` object. I want to put objects which `relatedId` s equal parents `Id`. Like i said i just want to cast `List<Categories>` to `List<NewCategories>`.

Comment: to get the `List<NewCategories>`, we have to **project** the query using **select**, we need to initialize instances of `NewCategories` from `Categories`, all the other properties of `NewCategories` are able to be inferred from the `Categories` but the `SubCategories` is a question. Looks like you want to put/map `Categories1` from `Categories` to `SubCategories` in `NewCategories`?

Comment: Yes, exactly thats what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to create a `recursive` method to convert `Categories` to `NewCategories`, something like this (I'm not sure if it works, but it's worth trying):

```
public NewCategories ConvertToNewCategories(Categories cat){
  NewCategories nc = new NewCategories {Id = cat.CategoryId, Name = cat.CategoryName};
  nc.SubCategories.AddRange(cat.Categories1.Select(c=>ConvertToNewCategories(c)));
  return nc;
}
//Then
List<NewCategories> categories = db.Categories.Where(item => item.RelatedId == null)
                                              .Select(item=>ConvertToNewCategories(item))
                                              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Using it like this threw an exception `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'GeneralTestProject.Categories ConvertToNewCategories(Test.Data.Categories)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` But using this method after `db.Categories.Where(item => item.RelatedId == null).ToList();` worked flawlessly :) Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @ergunysr I didn't notice you use `EF`, I'm pretty sure that it should work for `LINQ-to-SQL` (and of course `LINQ-to-Object`), thanks for your response.